# Python Camera Calibration using Checkerboard

Tags: image-processing, camera-calibration

Im pretty new to image processing, but I have tried using the generic python opencv approach to finding the corners for one of my 8 views, but opencv's can't find the corners. I have attached an image of the captured checkerboard (these are unfortunately the best that could be captured and have several more like this to calibrate). I would greatly appreciate help getting started on finding a reliable way to capture the corners. If I could also get some advise on how to calibrate all of the 8 views together as well.

Thanks!

I tried using opencv's find corners function with the generic criteria and varying the rows and columns for the corners to look for. What I found was that I could get a view corners to be found for 2 columns and 2 columns, but other than that I could not get it to work. I then used Matlab's camera calibration and was able to get that to work, but I would prefer to use python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I'm also pretty new to this, but here are some quick tips, that worked for me with opencv findChessboardCorners in python:

1. It is recommended (if not required) that you have an odd number of columns and an even number of rows, or vice versa, but not both the same.
2. Transform to grayscale, if you haven't done so already
3. It can help if you run the detection on grayscale, and if it doesn't find anything **flip** the image gray values (255-image). This made my detection go from 0 to 100% - on my images.
4. Also obvious things: make sure the images are not blurry, the checkerboard in the images are not to small and the more images you have the better (generally, the absolute minimum is 6, but >~30 would be better).

I hope these tips help!